# Como "Copiar e Colar" um formulário em VBA?

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba

Tenho um formulário pronto que quero aproveitar tudo o que fiz para ele mas em um outro formulário, seria o caso de fazer algo similar ao "Copiar e Colar", tem como fazer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Há uma forma que encontrei para fazer, para testar *crie um formulário e coloque um botão nele* apenas para conferir a cópia depois.

**Para “copiar”**, primeiro, no **Project Explorer** clique com o botão direito do mouse sobre o nome do formulário que quer copiar, então selecione "**Exportar arquivo...**", e salve com o mesmo nome em uma pasta (p.ex.: **UserForm1**).

Depois, abra o formulário que quer copiar e chame as **Propriedades**, alterando o seu nome usando a **Propriedade “Name”** (p.ex.: alterar para **UserForm2**).

**Para “colar”**, volte a usar o botão direito do mouse e use a opção “**Importar arquivo...**”, selecione o mesmo arquivo que salvou e confirme (neste exemplo, o **UserForm1**).

Pronto, veja que ambos estão presentes e ambos com o mesmo botão da forma que estava no formulário original. É uma forma de fazer o “**copiar e colar**” para um formulário no **VBA**.

Atente para mudar o **Caption** do formulário novo, pois na verdade ele não é novo, uma vez que somente o seu nome foi alterado, o resto permanecerá igual (neste exemplo, o **Caption** do **UserForm2** continuará com “**UserFomr1**”). É isso.